# Динамическое добавление строки в ExpandableListView

Tags: android, listview, expandablelistview, xamarin

У меня имеется Expandable ListView.
Мне необходимо "внедрять" динамично,новые View в ListView. Для этого имеется что то типа шаблона для строки(назовем её к примеру DynamicControl.axml).

Я делаю следующее:

```
View _view = LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.DynamicControl,null);
```

После этого я внедряю мою вьюшку,в лист(expandable),посредством метода `AddView()`.

```
_List.AddView(_view,0); //где 0 это позиция(index)
```

После,я использую мой кастомный адаптер,в который добавляю следующее :

```
_List.SetAdapter(new _Adapter(this, List<MyClass>, _List));
```

В итоге получаю эксепшн :

> java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: addView(View) is not
>   supported in AdapterView

Гугл говорит(и IDE),мол AddView() не поддерживается AdapterView и мне необходимо использовать только тот самый адаптер,для изменения вьюшки в листе.
Если оно и так,то зачем было вводить такие плюшки как AddHeader/FooterView,которые работают на ура(и внедряют в конец\начало листа,то что мне нужно,но для динамических строк).
Мне нужно что то типо такого : https://i.stack.imgur.com/5LhLA.png , где :

```
"My New View" - // строка для Expandable ListView,которая состоит из того самого шаблона(про которй я писал выше). По сути это RelativeLayout(внути которого добавлен TextView).
```

PS Что вообще можно сделать ? Существует ли обход?

Comment: Вам нужен Header (view другого вида, чем элементы в списке) для `ExpandableListView` или просто добавить такой же элемент в начало списка?

Comment: у меня была похожая ситуация, когда над ListView надо было динамически создавать вьюхи сверху, но я не 'header' использовал, а положил ListView внутрь ScrollView, немного поигрался с прокруткой и в итоге все работало… Если интересно, могу поискать что я там сделал…

Comment: @pavlofff мне нужно добавлять другие вьюшки,в разные позиции(к примеру в начало листа,затем в середину и так далее). Header это был как пример,того что мне нужно.

Comment: @evp Header это был как пример,мне нужно вставлять в разные позиции,динамические вьюшки. Было бы неплохо если бы ты показал что ты сделал.

Comment: @VetaLio то, что предлагает **evp**  - адский костыль. Эти ваши вьюшки - их разметка такая же, как и у остальных элементов, для всех добавляемых одна, но не такая, как у элементов списка, каждый раз разная?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем решение(для меня),это использование пост условия,благодаря которому я буду выбирать необходимый мне контейнер :

```
  if(!SpecificLayout)
    {
      var inflater = _context.GetSystemService(Context.LayoutInflaterService) as  LayoutInflater;
      view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.SpecificLayout, null);
    }
  else
    {
      var inflater = _context.GetSystemService(Context.LayoutInflaterService) as  LayoutInflater;
      view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.AnotherLayout, null);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

В списки элементы добавлять надо так:

1. Создать экземпляр объекта данных, которые отображаются списком через адаптер
2. Добавить этот экземпляр в список данных адаптера
3. Уведомить адаптер, что данные изменились и он должен себя перерисовать

AddHeader/FooterView делают примерно тоже самое, обёртывая адаптер списка другим адаптером (т.е. это костыль, сделанный для уменьшения гемороя с типами элементов списка).

Comment: Почему тогда AddView вообще  приминим к контролу ListView ? Не понимаю логики

Comment: @VetaLio потому,что `ListView` - наследник `ViewGroup`

Comment: @pavlofff а нельзя никак обратиться к адаптеру обертки от Header/Footer'a ?

Answer (score 0):

lv - листвью
sv - scrollview
lastY - float переменная - приватная, объявленная в классе
понятно, что внутри scrollVieewимеется какой-нить layout и внутри уже layout находится наш ListView

...

```
lv.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        int action = event.getAction();
        boolean canScrollUp = lv.canScrollVertically(-1);
        boolean canScrollDown = lv.canScrollVertically(1);
    if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            lastY = event.getY();
            sv.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(canScrollDown || canScrollUp);

        } else if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            sv.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);

        } else if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE){
            if (event.getY() > lastY){ // тащим палец вниз, если в листвью есть айтемы сверху, тогда запрещаем сколлвью скролиться, скролится листвью и наоборот
                sv.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(canScrollUp);
            }else{ //тащим палец вверх, если в листвью имеются айтемы внизу (он может скролиться вниз), тогда запрещаем скролиться скролвью, скролится листвью
                sv.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(canScrollDown);
            }

            lastY = event.getY();
        }
    return false;
}
```

});

Comment: благодарю,но это немного не то.